# How do you delete all the documents from a Cloudant Database or even Delete the database in Bluemix

Tags: database, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have been working on the Bluemix demo templates and have filled up a Cloudant database with 12k documents.  Now I want to start over as this is test data, and want to start with a clean database.

[lots of documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhXLU.jpg)

I found I could interactively delete documents 100 at a time, but I need to just start over with a clean database.

Is there a command or menu option for this?

I tried making a new database, which was easy, but i didn't find a way to delete the old one or then rename the new one.

thanks
john

Answer (score 3):

You could perform a [DELETE request to your database](https://docs.cloudant.com/database.html#deleting-a-database):

`curl -X DELETE https://username:password@username.cloudant.com/yourdatabase`

The answer indicates whether you succeeded.

As an alternative you can use the Dashboard (GUI). Once you are on the database panel and selected a single database, click the icon for `settings` and select `Delete`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the existing database but remove the documents, you can use CouchDB's [Bulk API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html).

Make a call to the [all_docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html) end point to retrieve the current list of all document identifiers and revision. For each document retrieved, consisting the the *_id* and *_rev* fields, add a *_deleted* field with value *true*.

Now send a HTTP POST to the _bulk_docs end point for the database, with the updated documents list.

```
POST /database/_bulk_docs HTTP/1.1

{
    "docs": [
        {
            "_id": "some_document_id",
            "_rev": "1-6a466d5dfda05e613ba97bd737829d67",
            "_deleted": true
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Full details on the Bulk API are [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html#updating-documents-in-bulk).

Deleted documents will remain in your database until you run the [purge](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Purge_Documents) command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this within to dashboard, select the database you want then select the settings cog by the DB name. You'll see a Delete option.